# iOS string expression to integer value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a string: "1+2+3232+4" which I would like to turn the answer: 3239.

How do I do this in Objective-C?

Comment: Only addition ?
A way to do it, would be to use `componentsSeparatedByString` which return a `NSArray`, do the addition, and then convert into an `int`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For simple expressions, you can use [`NSExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html):

```
NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"1+2+3232+4"];
NSNumber *result = [e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

For more complicated expression, you should use a proper math expression parser,
e.g. https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser.

*Remark:* One potential problem with this approach can be that integers are not
automatically converted to floating point numbers. For example,
`"4/3"` evaluates to `1`, not to `1.3333333`.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *string = @"1+2+3232+4";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];

NSInteger result = 0;
for (NSString *value in array)
   result += [value integerValue];
NSLog(@"%i", result);
```

Comment: Just a remark: You could also use Key-Value Coding to compute the sum: `NSNumber *sum = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];`

Answer (score 0):

This is use for **float/int** Value also

```
NSString *myStringNumber = @"5+1+2+3.5+4/5+3.5*86";
NSArray *convertNumber = [myStringNumber componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
float sumValue = 0;
for (NSString *number in convertNumber) {
   sumValue += [number floatValue];
}
NSLog(@"Result is : %f", sumValue);
```